# Icon Font No Longer Displaying Character on WordPress Site since I upload a plugin

Tags: wordpress, icons

Here is my Wordpress website : http://vps319156.ovh.net/

The icons are not displaying correctly since I upload a new plugin Visual line for Visual Composer.

I desinstalled the plugin and try to reinstall the font but it did not work.

The weird part is that I have one Icon working...

I tried many solutions from the web and could not find out one that is workable in my case..

Comment: use private browser

Comment: .icon-facebook2 ??

Comment: which Icon shows?

Comment: You are loading same font many time this conflict your theme,I suggest to deactive font-awesome,font-awesome-wp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the plugin font-awesome that is overriding iconfont.css definitions and so on, the `[class^="icon-"]`.

It seems that the fontawesome related fonts are not found in the plugin font-awesome.

The `plugins/font-awesome/assets/font-awesome.min.css` couldn't find the font `../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot`

Correct the path or copy the fonts file at this place.

In the browser dev tools, when you unclick fontawesome class, icons are display, it's just the enqueue priority to modify, it depends if you want to display, font-awesome icons or iconfonts.css icons.

Comment: Is it display??